# Unused gRPC ServerContext

Tags: grpc

I am new to gRPC and trying to use it in my existing system. However, I get this unused parameter error while compiling it.

```
server_grpc.cc:100:39: error: unused parameter ‘context’[-Werror=unused-parameter]
    Status MyFunc(ServerContext* context, const QueryRequest* request,
```

Probably the context parameter is used in some other cases. But, in simple `hello world` type of example it is not used. Is there a way to compile the protocol buffer without generating the `ServerContext` parameter ?

I know I can make the compiler ignore warning messages. But, just wondering if it can be done without affecting the way my system is being compiled right now.

I would like to know how the context is used ? It would be great if anybody can give pointers to how to use this context. I might find a use of it in my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ServerContext` is provided to, well, add context for every RPC you get. It'll allow you to tweak certain aspects of the RPC, such as deal with authentication, or add metadata to your response back to the client. You may or may not need that parameter, obviously, depending on your needs.

We didn't want to add an option for this specifically, because that'd complexify the code and tool for little benefit, so the code generator and the function signature force you to have that parameter at all times. Now this isn't really a big deal, because in C++, you can specifically ask your compiler to ignore a parameter in a specific instance, for example with the following:

```cpp
  Status SayHello(ServerContext* context, const HelloRequest* request,
                  HelloReply* reply) override {
    (void) context; // ignore that variable without causing warnings
    std::string prefix("Hello ");
    reply->set_message(prefix + request->name());
    return Status::OK;
  }
```

And that's how I'd suggest you to take care of that warning in that specific instance, without causing your whole project to not have warnings enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Hope the gRPC documentation improves a little bit more showing examples of using this Context.